# search a unicode string in a file using java

Tags: java, string, file, search, unicode

How to search a unicode string in a file using java?
Below is the code that I have tried.It works strings other than unicode.

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    class file1
    {
   public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
   {
    BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter File name:");
    String str = bfr1.readLine();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    int count=0;
    int flag=0;

    System.out.println("Enter the string to be found");
    s=br.readLine();
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str));
    String bfr2=bfr.readLine();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s);
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(bfr2);
            while (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            }System.out.println(count);
   }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are three potential sources of problems I can see:

- The regular expression may be incorrect. Do you really *need* to use a regular expression? Are you trying to match a pattern, or just a simple string?
- You may be failing to get non-ASCII input from the command line. You should dump out the input string in terms of its Unicode characters (see code later).
- You may well be reading the file in the wrong encoding. Currently you're using `FileReader` which always uses the platform default encoding. What's the encoding of the file you're trying to read? I would recommend using `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` using an explicit encoding (e.g. UTF-8) which matches the file.

To debug the *real* values in strings, I would usually use something like this:

```
private static void dumpString(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        System.out.printf("%d: %4h (%c)", i, c, c);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

That way you can see the exact UTF-16 code point in each `char` in the string.